# Laravel & Vue - Sentry Not Logging Errors from JS Within Blades

Tags: laravel, vue.js, sentry

I have a website running on Laravel & Vue JS. I have recently integrated Sentry for catching front-end errors. Integrated the Vue solution. However, it is not catching errors from JS included within blades. If I implement a Sentry JS solution, it doesn't catch Vue errors. Can anybody suggest what to do here?

Comment: Is it logging any of your js errors, and only missing Vue errors? Sentry's vue package relies on the js sdk to be configured I believe. Have you followed https://docs.sentry.io/platforms/javascript/?

Comment: I have installed using the Vue SDK in Laravel's app.js and yes it tracks JS errors happening in Vue